# Why does setting ComboBox.SelectedValue to null cause a ArgumentNullException?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datasource, nullreferenceexception

Why does setting the `SelectedValue` of a `ComboBox` to `null` cause an `ArgumentNullException`?

The Exception only occurs if the ComboBox is actually part of a Form.
I can set `SelectedValue` to all kinds of values or types that don't make sense, but I can't set it to `null`.

It's not that `SelectedValue` can not be `null`. In fact, its value *is* `null` at the time I'm trying to set it to `null`.

In my real code, this doesn't happen in the constructor, and I'm not excplicitly setting it to `null`. The code is using a variable which happens to be `null`. I can fix it by checking of the variable isn't `null` before trying to set the `SelectedValue`. But what I don't understand is *why* I can't set it to a `null` value.

**Code edit**: DataSource now contains an item where the ValueMembers value is actually `null`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        var comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
        Controls.Add(comboBox1);
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        comboBox1.DataSource = new List<Record> {
            new Record {Key = "1", Value = "One"}, 
            new Record {Key = null, Value = "null"}
        };
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = null;          // no problem
        comboBox1.SelectedValue = "";           // no problem
        comboBox1.SelectedValue = new object(); // no problem
        comboBox1.SelectedValue = null;         // ArgumentNullException!!
    }
}

public class Record {
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have code linked to SelectedIndexChanged event or some other event triggered by the change of the current value?

Comment: See if this question can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864065/c-sharp-set-combo-item-with-selectedvalue/2864119

Comment: @Steve: No. The above sample code is a complete working example showing the exception.

Answer (score 6):

Inspecting the implementation of the property in `Reflector` it looks like this:

```
public object SelectedValue
{
    get
    {
        if ((this.SelectedIndex != -1) && (this.dataManager != null))
        {
            object item = this.dataManager[this.SelectedIndex];
            return this.FilterItemOnProperty(item, this.valueMember.BindingField);
        }
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this.dataManager != null)
        {
            string bindingField = this.valueMember.BindingField;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bindingField))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("ListControlEmptyValueMemberInSettingSelectedValue"));
            }
            PropertyDescriptor property = this.dataManager.GetItemProperties().Find(bindingField, true);
            int num = this.dataManager.Find(property, value, true);
            this.SelectedIndex = num;
        }
    }
}
```

So this seems to hinge on `this.dataManager` not being null.

If `this.dataManager` isn't null, the setter will call `Find()` with `key` set to the value that you're setting `SelectedValue` to:

```
internal int Find(PropertyDescriptor property, object key, bool keepIndex)
{
    if (key == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
    }
    if (((property != null) && (this.list is IBindingList)) && ((IBindingList) this.list).SupportsSearching)
    {
        return ((IBindingList) this.list).Find(property, key);
    }
    if (property != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.list.Count; i++)
        {
            object obj2 = property.GetValue(this.list[i]);
            if (key.Equals(obj2))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Which will throw an exception if `key` is null.

I'm guessing that `dataManager` is only set to non-null when the ComboBox is inserted into a container (e.g. a Form) which is why it doesn't blow up when it's not in a container.

(In fact, `dataManager` will be set to non-null when you set the `Control.DataSource` property to non-null.)

<strike>However, this doesn't seem quite right, because you reported a `NullReferenceException` and this clearly throws an `ArgumentNullException`.</strike>

[EDIT] It was indeed an `ArgumentNullExeption`; OP has been updated accordingly.

Comment: +1 for quick and thorough "rubber glove" analysis as it were.  I noted that the exception thrown is actually `ArgumentNullException`...but didn't note initially that `key` was the offending parameter, that the setter itself was not the source of the exception.  Strong work. :}

Comment: I'm sorry, the exception thrown is indeed the ArgumentNullException. I will change my post.

Comment: So the question now becomes why the Find method doesn't accept `null` as its `key` value. It *is* possible to create a `Record` with a `key` of `null` and add it to the `DataSource`. But you wouldn't be able to set `SelectedValue` to that value.

Comment: @comecme: The answer to why `Find` doesn't accept a `null` for `key` is right in the opening of its body - `if (key == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("key"); }`.

Comment: @J0e3gan I see that. That's why the code is throwing the exception. But _why_ is that line in there? I've updated my code to show that's it's perfectly fine to have an item where the DataMember property has a `null` value. I would expect to be able to set the SelectedValue to `null` as it is a valid value in this case.

Answer (score 2):

My guess was that this may be a miss on what should be an `ArgumentNullException` rather than a `NullReferenceException` (thrown in the property setter's implementation).

On quickly checking the code you provided (plus a `Main` method with `var form1 = new Form1()`), though, I find that I do not actually get a `NullReferenceException` like you describe but rather an `ArgumentNullException` like I expect I should.

Are you sure that you noted the exception type correctly?

**UPDATE:**

As Matthew Watson describes, the parameter indicated by the `ArgumentNullException` is, in fact, `key`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because if the property ValueMember of SelectedValue is Nothing, then the SelectedValue will return .ToString() on the SelectedItem.

Answer (score 0):

On the button_click, this code fonctionned and deleted **ArgumentNullException** :

```
if (comboBoxPays.SelectedValue == null)
{
  id_pays = 0;
}
else
  id_pays = int.Parse(comboBoxPays.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I have the same error right now and I have find that I cannot set SelectedValue = null but I did managed to set it to DBNull.Value