# Most Elegant Way to Set ComboBox by Value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm usually doing web stuff so pardon any ignorance on the topic.

I'm trying to do the Load a combobox from the codebehind like this:

```
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConStr)) {
        try {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_SelectContactDropDown", con) {                           
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };                                      

                var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter {SelectCommand = cmd};
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                ((ComboBox) Controls.Find(ddContact, true)[0]).DataSource = dt;
                ((ComboBox) Controls.Find(ddContact, true)[0]).DisplayMember = "DisplayText";
                ((ComboBox) Controls.Find(ddContact, true)[0]).ValueMember = "ID";
                ((ComboBox) Controls.Find(ddContact, true)[0]).SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
            finally { /* Handle the error*/ }
```

Where ID is an int.  After this I want to set the selected value of the combo box based on the value member.  However this seems to be allot trickier then I would think it needs to be.  In asp this is pretty straightforward

```
        ddContact.SelectedValue = o.fk_ContactID.ToString();
```

I've checked out some other questions ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864065/c-sharp-set-combo-item-with-selectedvalue),[Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450059/c-sharp-how-do-i-set-the-selected-item-in-a-combobox-to-match-my-string?rq=1)) which seem to be referring to setting the value by the display member.  Whats the most elegant way to go about this ?  Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Why do you use Controls.Find? the direct syntax (if on the same class) works

Comment: Just don't use `ToString()`. Unlike ASP.NET, which operates strings, WinForms uses type-sensitive comparison.

Comment: @Steve, to be fair he said he was ignorant on the topic - and so your comment is rather moot :)

Comment: @AlexSkalozub It appears that problem was ToString() Call.  If you make that an answer I'll mark it as such.  Thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say WinForms, so, unless the combo is in another class, this should work

```
ddContact.DisplayMember = "DisplayText";
ddContact.ValueMember = "ID";
ddContact.DataSource = dt;
ddContact.Value = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["ID"]);
```

Also I assume that you have found at least one record from your query