# Combobox set selected value from SQL

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two tables in database, `Notes` and `Categories` (with `Notes` having a foreign key to `Categories`).

I have loaded data from table `Notes` and in combobox from table category.

Now I need to select the same category(foreign key) as in note in the combobox.

My code is :

```
DataTable dtCat = qc.getCategory();
cmbCategory.DataSource = dtCat;
cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "categoryName";
cmbCategory.ValueMember = "categoryId";
cmbCategory.SelectedValue = "categoryId";
```

Comment: SelectedValue shouldn't be the column name.  Check here for an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864065/c-sharp-set-combo-item-with-selectedvalue

Comment: @Andez i tried this , it shows  '-1'  
 `MessageBox.Show(cmbCategory.FindStringExact("Bird").ToString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("categoryName");
dt.Columns.Add("categoryId");

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Cat1", "1"});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Cat2", "2"});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Cat3", "3"});

this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "categoryName";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "categoryId";

this.comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

this.comboBox1.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[1]["categoryId"]; // select Cat2
```

So you can specify the selected value by the categoryId column in the Row Values of the DataTable.